# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

This is rapidly becoming a hot issue across the entire network: how to promote your site and how to reach out to the experts and peers in *your* industry. We can come up with budgets and promotions but the means and ideas about how to reach your target audience HAS TO come from you and your community. Has to. Has to, has to, *has to!* We simply are not experts in your field. We don’t have the the connections nor the experience you bring to the table. You are both our evangelist and our ambassador — and [sharing links to great questions and answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) is the best way to start.

[image]

Stack Overflow has been a huge, red-hot success story in the programming arena. But that early success came in large part to the participation of Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, both cult-classic bloggers and celebrities in their field. We want that same success for you and your community. That’s why we need to identify the Jeffs and the Joels of *your* industry. We need bloggers, pundits, podcasters, publishers, celebrities… anyone who can rally the troops, so to speak.

Meta is the perfect venue reach out and ask around about who knows whom. Ask your friends to ask their friends. The people needed to make your site a huge success are already within your reach.

For more detail see: [A Recipe to Promote Your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Comment: [Similar discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/811/how-can-we-make-new-consistent-followers-ideas) and [Ideas](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/699/creating-facebook-page-for-movies-se).

Comment: @Mistu4, have you ended learning English? I don't see you so often as I do the last two months.

Comment: @Carlo_R, Not at all, actually I have been busy with my college semesters! I will be back and active after it ends (probably the semester will end till the end of this month). Though I visit this site time-to-time.

Comment: Also [related discussion](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/385/133).

Answer (score 4):

I think we ought to have a regular chat for people to practice their English.  We could mix non-native and native speakers together and cover some conversation basics and answer etiquette questions.  We could advertise it on the other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

To promote this site, I think is the most important is to answer the questions.

I started using it a few months ago and it was absolutely great. I came form ELU where my questions were down voted as to simple for them. I was very happy with ELL and felt good with it.

I asked question today and have three comments. One provide link to question in ELU, which in my feeling does not give me an answer I need. Another comment gives link to writers.eu and another comment is so general that I can't apply it.

After a half day I don't have an answer and still don't know what to do with my problem.

I checked recent questions and there is quite a few questions down-voted. I understand that it could be said they to general, but on the end of the day for learners it is also difficult to ask a good question. Often if you know how to ask very good question in English you probably know what is the answer for it.

I think this site is a bit different than stack exchange, which is for experts. This site is for learners and to promote it it should be understand and if I can say - "respected".

Comment: There are exactly 6 questions out of almost 1800 which have no answer yet.  You got, within half an hour, a Comment asking a question you never bothered to answer; within an hour and a half, a Comment providing at least a partial answer; within 15 hours, an actual Answer. Half the answers here come from  just 12 people, two thirds by less than 30, working folk all over the world, on all sorts of schedules, who're here when they can be. ***Cut us some slack, man! :)***

Comment: @StoneyB before I write anything further I would like to be clear about one point. The ELL side is great. People like you, with your reputation do absolutely amazing job. If you feel any offended by what I wrote, simply remove my answer from the system because it is not understood how it should be.

Comment: @StoneyB I think that power of Stack Exchange is that there is really vibrant community. In my answer I wanted to write that I am surprise by lack of answer (I don't argue it is there now). I am surprise for so many down-voted questions as it looks for me as a learner, they are normal learner's questions. I am also surprise by answers as: "... check on another website...". This is what I wanted to write and one more time, what I wrote is only as "what to do to promote" it is not a complain, it is not an offence or not other thing. You do great job and I am grateful for it.

Comment: No offense taken ... the pointer to ELU was, I think, intended to ask whether this was what you were talking about. As for downvotes, I wouldn't fret too much; they're not about your question itself but about how useful a voter thinks it will be **to other learners**.